# PHP - Is danger to use mysqli connect without die() when connect error?

Tags: php, mysqli, die

Is danger to use mysqli connect without die() when connect error and if so why?

Comment: Danger of what; and using `die()` is never a good idea if it can be avoided (and it always can be avoided); you should provide a clean response to the front-end

Comment: `die()` will show the blank screen, instead of this, redirect visitors to Maintenance page.. and show any notification message.